# Looking for a better way to create an edited copy of a file

Tags: python

I have downloaded the UK Charity Commission's data which comes in the form of several BCP files. For each of these files I want to create a new CSV file containing a cleaned copy of the data. I have a solution that works, but I suspect there are better ways of doing it.

The First thing to note is that it's not as simple as reading the BCP files into, say, pandas CSV reader with the appropriate delimiters and line terminators. The BCP file's underlying text file contains line breaks which confuse CSV readers. These need to be removed to get the right result.

Moreover since the delimiter is `@**@` and the line terminator is `*@@*`, and since there are many empty fields, it is not uncommon to have a pair of delimiters adjacent to each other in the file which can be read a line terminator.

```
def bcp_converter(bcp_file, columns):
    with open(bcp_file, 'r', encoding='Latin-1') as bcpfile:
        with open(bcp_file[:-4] + '.csv', 'w+', encoding='Latin-1') as csvfile:
            csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
            csvwriter.writerow(columns)
            temp_line = ''
            for line in bcpfile:
                temp_line = temp_line + (line.replace('\n', '')
                                         .replace('\r', '')
                                         .replace('&#x0D;', '')
                                         .replace('\x07\t', '')
                                         .replace('@**@','%%')
                                         .replace('*@@*', '\n'))

                csv_data = [[string.strip() for string in item.split('%%')] for item in temp_line.split('\n')[:-1]]

                temp_line = temp_line.split('\n')[-1] + ' '

                for i in range(len(csv_data)):
                    csvwriter.writerow(csv_data[i])

        csvfile.close()
```

This code works, and it's not too slow (it takes about 1min30 on my PC to convert ~700MB of data), however I suspect there are ways I could make it better.

As a side note there is a publicly available converter on GitHub - https://github.com/ncvo/charity-commission-extract/ . However, whilst this works reasonably well, it does make several mistakes (in several cases the fax column ends up containing strings which clearly aren't faxes, and attempts to force the regno column to be an int in pandas fail). This is the reason I decided to write my own.

Comment: This is more a matter for CodeReview, but structurally I would merely recommend splitting on the delimiters rather than translating them and splitting on the result (what if there were a %% in a field value?).  Also, why `w+` and `range`?

Comment: I wasn't aware of CodeReview, but I'll use it in future. Leaving the delimiters as is doesn't work since ``@**@@**@`` appears regularly and results in the converter reading a line terminator. I checked that ``%%`` doesn't appear, though I agree it's not an ideal solution. As for ``w+`` and ``range``: the former is me not reading the documentation properly and thinking the ``+`` was required to create a new file, the latter has now been changed to ``for row in csv_data:``.

Comment: If you `split` in the same order that you `replace`, shouldn’t it work just as well?

Comment: No. For example consider the string `1@**@2@**@3*@@*`. If I split by `@**@` followed by `*@@*` this returns `[['1'], ['2'], ['3', '']]`, whereas if I split by `*@@*` followed by `@**@` it returns `[['1', '2', '3'], ['']]`. The resulting CSV files will be different (transposes of each other), and the one I actually want requires me to split in the opposite order that I replaced.

Comment: Don’t retain the divisions from the first split when performing the second; split into “pseudo-fields” (that might be the last field of one line and the first of the next), then accumulate them into an output line until one of them produces two true fields from the second split.  It seems complicated, but can be viewed as an elegant pipeline (and implemented with generators to show that).

Comment: I've just written a generator which yields the appropriate CSV data row by row and avoids replacing the delimiters or line terminators. It seems to run a little faster than the old method (~1min to convert all the data vs. ~1min20) and I tend to agree that it seems a more elegant solution. I've also learnt about generators as a result. Thanks for your feedback.